# Hibernate one to one relation-ship mapping

Tags: sql, hibernate, database-design, shopping-cart, one-to-one

I made a one to one relation-ship between two tables for a shopping-card application, the relation between Customer and Card,

```
CREATE TABLE `card` (
'card_id' INT NOT NULL,
'product_id` INT NOT NULL,
`customer_id` INT UNIQUE ,
`product_quantity` INT,
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`card_id`),
KEY `FK_Customer` (`customer_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_Customer` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer`(`customer_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
`customer_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`photo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`balance` double DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the problem is that when hibernate generate entities, the customer.java is as follows:

```
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer customerId;
private String email;
private String name;
private String password;
private String photo;
private Double balance;
private Set cards = new HashSet(0);
}
```

.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Customer" table="customer" catalog="shopping_card">
    <id name="customerId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="customer_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="email" type="string">
        <column name="email" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="password" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="photo" type="string">
        <column name="photo" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="balance" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="balance" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <set name="cards" table="card" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="customer_id" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Card" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

the one to one relation is translated to one to many, i expect the Customer.java to have a Card instance variable instead of a Set of cards, what is the problem?

Comment: How do you generate entities, using hbm or schema ddl direclty?

Comment: i'm using hbm to generate the entities

Comment: an edit have been made

Comment: It seems you mapping customer-cards as a set? It's reasonable that the generated code reflect this mapping.

Comment: but in the script above i made the customer_id `customer_id` INT UNIQUE to avoid it to be translated as a one to many relation-ship

Comment: Why not use a one-to-one mapping? I have to confess that I'm not familiar with code generating.

Comment: i'm using hibernate code generation, i want to know why this relation is translated to one to many??